# cant find previously stored data on the hard disk

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it was a piece of cake.  The problem though is that I'm unable to see my previously stored data.  It was not formatted during installation, I just upgraded it and it said it would keep all my files intact.

Can u help me to restore them or view them or at least free my disk space by wiping them off.  There are no partitions or any other OS other than Ubuntu, its a 120 GB hard disk and before installation the free space was around 45gb or so and now its showing as 39gb and I'm unable to access the data.  kindly help & thanks in advance

Comment: How you upgraded your os? Using update manager or cdrom? Where you stored your files? In home folder or another partition?

Comment: using cdrom and i stored it in homefolder..there arw no partitions

Answer (score 0):

Probably you used new username while upgrading via cdrom , so it created new user account . You can see files in old home folder at /home

open the terminal and type `nautilus /home`

Comment: cool man ..it works..bt do i have to do it each time i want to view my files... or should i copy them here again

Comment: Creating a new user with old username may work . But I think cut and paste to new home folder is better

Comment: And reinstalling the os with specifying old username also will work